# How to Deploy rails app to Digital Ocean without Asset precompile error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, server, asset-pipeline, digital-ocean

I am a Newbie trying to deploy a rails app to Digital Ocean.

Any time I change any of the CSS I get an error when running cap production deploy.

Here is the output:

> 01:04 deploy:assets:precompile
>         01 ls /home/studentloaniq/releases/20200208140055/assets_manifest_backup
>         01 ls:
>         01 cannot access '/home/studentloaniq/releases/20200208140055/assets_manifest_backup'
>         01 : No such file or directory
>         01
>         02 /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm ruby-2.6.0 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
>         02 Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
>         02 Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
>         02 rake aborted!
>         02 TypeError: no implicit conversion of Encoding into String

Comment: Have you had a successful deploy to production with this setup before this issue began occurring?